# Spring batch stateful processor

Tags: spring-batch, stateful

I am trying to use spring batch to read from a database and write to console. I already implemented a database reader using the class JdbcCursorItemReader. The problem is that the objects in the database are spread among several different rows. For example if I want to create the Person object I will have something like this:

firstName  lastName  week salary 
carlos        Palma      1    150   
carlos        Palma      2    120

Now I want to create an object that looks like this:

```
public class Person{
 String firstName;
 String lastName;
 List<Salary> payment;

}
```

where the Salary object looks like this:

```
public class Salary{
  String week;
  Integer salary;

}
```

I have seen examples of spring batch but the processor usually just transforms the current row into something else. Is there a way to have some memory of multiple rows to create the final object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is not possible to do that with an aggregation query on the database side, you could use the driving query pattern. The idea of this pattern is that the item reader reads only the person's details (firtname, lastname) and the item processor enriches the current item with additional details (salaries in your case). This is described in the [Driving Query Based ItemReaders](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.3.x/reference/html/common-patterns.html#drivingQueryBasedItemReaders) section of the documentation.

Note that this pattern works well for small datasets, but not so well for large datasets as it requires an additional query for each item.